# Removing the word "SharePoint" from top of page in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage

**Problem:** I want to remove the word "SharePoint" from the top of the page.

I've researched this for a while now and tried various methods (all focused on SP2013). However, I'm using SharePoint 2016. I am also using SPD2013 (obviously).

The **approaches** taken so far have followed some web searches and have been offered by MVPs and high-rep MSDN forum-goers. I am happy to assume I'm doing something wrong. The approaches I've taken so far include:

- Create a Master page copy, add a line to reference a custom.css file. This supposedly makes a change. (URL: https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/sharepoint-2013-how-to-change-sharepoint-branding-text-in-the-upper-left-part-of-your-screen)
- Create a Master page copy and <%-- comment out --%> a line referencing delegatecontrol
- Add some javascript directly on to the page. (I tried this one with some skepticism I'll admit)
- Others that I simply can't remember. Please excuse my being vague with the above. I didn't copy all my efforts of the URLs visited.

**Has anyone managed this in SP 2016?** Even 2013? Can you share a solution you've gotten working, please? It's worth noting I've never seen a screenshot of this successfully implemented alongside these suggestions. But then maybe I've gotten worn down by the failed efforts.

I'd love to remove the word "SharePoint" from every page. It's the sort of branding design choice that really should not be force-fed for an on-premise or hosted solution.

Comment: Checked this  ? - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138359/i-want-to-remove-the-sharepoint-label-from-the-suitebar-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: :) Thanks. I'm working through a video I've found on using JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You remove it completely using Powershell:

```
$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication "https://rootsitecollectionurl"
$webapp.SuiteNavBrandingText = ""
$webapp.Update()
```

[Change suitebar text using powershell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34202.sharepoint-2016-how-to-change-suitbars-text-powershell.aspx)

2) Using jquery :

In your custom masterpage, add the below line inside the `<head>` tag

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

After that, at the bottom of the master page near `</body>`, add the below code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('div#suiteBarLeft .ms-core-brandingText').text(""); //selectors could be different in 2016, press F12 and inspect the element
</script>
```

[remove sharepoint label from the suitebar in sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138359/i-want-to-remove-the-sharepoint-label-from-the-suitebar-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Fabulous. Thank you very much. Ran the Powershell option and it's working like a charm. Much preferred over dinking around with master pages.

Answer (score 2):

Why that 'great' jQuery?

Note: The CSS Selectors could me slightly different on your env. Check F12 Console,
and use Stylish or Stylebot plugin to test CSS changes live on a page

## CSS

```
.o365cs-nav-appTitleLine,
a.o365cs-nav-appTitle {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

You could use display:none but then your (optional) company logo in the center of the suitebar will move to the left

#### Add your Company name

[image]

```
a#O365_MainLink_Logo:after {
    content: "My Company name";
    margin-left: 1em;
    font-size: 2em;
    color:gold;
}
```

## JavaScript

If you do want the scripting solution, at least ditch jQuery and use vanilla JavaScript

```
document.querySelector('.o365cs-nav-appTitleLine').style.visibility='hidden';
document.querySelector('a.o365cs-nav-appTitle').style.visibility='hidden';
```

again; if you remove the text, a centered Company Logo will move to the left

Comment: I'm using SharePoint 2016 on-premise, and so I didn't start with this because it referenced O365. That said, thanks for taking the time. It will be appreciated when I need to work this solution for a O365 environment. I used the Powershell approach suggested below.

Comment: Open F12 console and check  what the CSS Selectors are named, apart from O365 they can't be much different