# How to remove the word "SharePoint" in the upper left corner of SP 16 On-Prem instead of just hiding the text

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, css, hide-elements

For a SharePoint 2016 on-prem site, I've figured out how to hide the word *"SharePoint"* in the upper left corner of a site collection, but I'd like to take that a step further and actually **remove the word** **"SharePoint"**.

*Is that possible via .css instead of PowerShell?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS is a language that describes the style of an HTML document. 
We can only **hide** the "SharePoint" element using CSS.

To **remove** the "SharePoint" text, we can also use script.

Here is the demo to remove "SharePoint" text in SharePoint 2016 using jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('div.o365cs-nav-o365Branding span .o365cs-nav-brandingText').text("");
</script>
```

For more information, you can refer to :

[Removing the word "SharePoint" from top of page in SharePoint 2016](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/207531/removing-the-word-sharepoint-from-top-of-page-in-sharepoint-2016)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide this element with:

To hide Suite Bar Links use the following CSS

```
#suiteLinksBox {
    display: none;
}
```

To hide a specific Link in Suite Bar like newsfeed:

```
#suiteLinksBox .ms-core-suiteLink-a[id$='ShellNewsfeed'] {
    display: none;
}
```

To hide the full Suite Bar:

```
#suiteBar {
    display: none;
}
```

More information [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/194278/edit-suite-bar-links-in-sharepoint-2016).